# Python 3.5 code - classes not correct defined

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I have a simple code problem and do not know what I do wrong. The import part is OK, when I get as an error message is that, I guess I make a mistake with the classes.

```
status_listener = SessionStatusListener()
TypeError: interface takes exactly one argument
```

So the code is:

```
import clr

clr.AddReference ("fxcore2")
from fxcore2 import O2GTransport, IO2GSessionStatus

class SessionStatusListener(IO2GSessionStatus):

    def __init__(self):
        IO2GSessionStatus.__init__(self)
        self.connected = False

    def onLoginFailed(self, error):
        print ("*** LOGIN FAILED: %s" % error)

    def onSessionStatusChanged(self, status):
        print ("NEW STATUS: %s" % status)
        if status == O2GSessionStatusCode.Connected:
            self.connected = True
```

The main Application starts here

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    session = O2GTransport.createSession()
    status_listener = SessionStatusListener()
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Nothing in your code could produce that error message; what does `IO2GSessionStatus.__init__` expect for arguments?

Comment: You probably need to pass `session` to `SessionStatusListener` (and pass it on to `IO2GSessionStatus`).

Answer (score 0):

Pass an argument to SessionStatusListener, like it's telling you to. I would imagine that you need to change the `__init__` body to something like

```
super().__init__(self)
```

instead of

```
IO2GSessionStatus.__init__(self)
```

Comment: Why would `super` change anything? Also, that call to `super` will pass the instance both as an implicit and an explicit argument.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is saying that

```
status_listener = SessionStatusListener()
```

Needs one argument, like this:

```
status_listener = SessionStatusListener(1)
```

I'm not sure exactly what types of data it's expecting, but you need to pass in an argument.

Comment: could it be that there is a problem with the heritage of objects between 2.7  and 3.5 ?